# Steam running Witcher 2

Tags: drivers, steam

Hi I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 14.03 and Steam after reinstalling Windows 7 as a dual boot. When I installed Steam originally the game The Witcher 2 seemed to run fine in lower graphic settings. Since I have reinstalled Steam it will not run I believe I installed something in package manager the first time round and cannot remember what the hell it was. Please can anyone help? Do I need to install graphics drivers? Or some other software for it to run? I can provide the error message if need be, though it is quite long.

Simon

Comment: What is your graphics hardware?

Comment: My graphics is Intel HD 4000

Answer (score 1):

From my limited experience gaming on Intel drivers, I would guess the thing you installed last time was the `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc` packages. These packages provide an open-source implementation of the `GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc` OpenGL feature that a lot of games require.

Install them and try again. You might need a reboot after installing the packages.